# How to left align a fixed width string?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I just want fixed width columns of text but the strings are all padded right, instead of left!!?

```
 sys.stdout.write("%6s %50s %25s\n" % (code, name, industry))
```

produces

```
BGA                                BEGA CHEESE LIMITED   Food Beverage & Tobacco
BHP                               BHP BILLITON LIMITED                 Materials
BGL                               BIGAIR GROUP LIMITED Telecommunication Services
BGG           BLACKGOLD INTERNATIONAL HOLDINGS LIMITED                    Energy
```

but we want

```
BGA BEGA CHEESE LIMITED                                Food Beverage & Tobacco
BHP BHP BILLITON LIMITED                               Materials
BGL BIGAIR GROUP LIMITED                               Telecommunication Services
BGG BLACKGOLD INTERNATIONAL HOLDINGS LIMITED           Energy
```

Comment: shweet! thanks... it had to be pretty simple. umm now with 3 simultaneous correct answers who gets the green tick?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can prefix the size requirement with `-` to left-justify:

```
sys.stdout.write("%-6s %-50s %-25s\n" % (code, name, industry))
```

Comment: Nice solution. This is the best solution.

Comment: what if my size/width values are variable ?

Comment: @ViFI you can use * symbol like this `'%-*sText'%(3,'A')`

Answer (score 52):

This version uses the [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method.

**Python 2.7 and newer**

```
sys.stdout.write("{:<7}{:<51}{:<25}\n".format(code, name, industry))
```

**Python 2.6 version**

```
sys.stdout.write("{0:<7}{1:<51}{2:<25}\n".format(code, name, industry))
```

**UPDATE**

Previously there was a statement in the docs about the % operator being removed from the language in the future. This statement has been [removed from the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23381153/1699750).

Comment: The old style is no longer going to be deprecated, I believe: http://bugs.python.org/issue14123

Comment: It looks like that issue is rejected. Stage: committed/rejected

Comment: That status is _also_ used to indicate "committed", which it definitely was because the changes were made to the documentation. What was "Old String Formatting Operations" in the 3.2 docs is now [printf-style String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) in 3.3. The _possible_ deprecation warning - it actually said "_may_ go away", it was never definitive - is now absent from that section as well, replaced with a warning about it being "quirky". It's not going away.

Comment: You are looking at a different part of the docs. The section [Old string formatting](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting)
 is still there in 3.3 docs it's under the tutorial section not the library reference. and the statement "this old style of formatting will eventually be removed from the language" is still there.

Comment: @Matthew - Disinformation is false information intended to mislead. I doubt Marwan had any such intentions.

Comment: Why isn't this in the docs... I had to google to find this answer and discover that "<" is used for left alignment :|

Answer (score 34):

With the new and popular **f-strings** in **Python 3.6**, here is how we left-align say a string with 16 padding length:

```
string = "Stack Overflow"
print(f"{string:<16}..")
Stack Overflow  ..
```

If you have variable padding length:

```
k = 20
print(f"{string:<{k}}..")
Stack Overflow      ..
```

**f-strings** are more compact.

Comment: `str` is a built-in in Python, so using that as an object name isn't ideal.

Comment: You can also put the direction character `>`, `<`, `^` etc, as a variable, so after `a="<"`, you can use: `f"{string:{a}{k}"`

Comment: It would have been helpful to add the option for what @user1767754 showed: the insertion of padding characters, e.g. by `f"{string:_<16}"` (the padding char in this case is '_').

Answer (score 32):

```
sys.stdout.write("%-6s %-50s %-25s\n" % (code, name, industry))
```

on a side note you can make the width variable with `*-s`

```
>>> d = "%-*s%-*s"%(25,"apple",30,"something")
>>> d
'apple                    something                     '
```

Answer (score 28):

I definitely prefer the `format` method more, as it is very flexible and can be easily extended to your custom classes by defining `__format__` or the `str` or `repr` representations. For the sake of keeping it simple, i am using `print` in the following examples, which can be replaced by `sys.stdout.write`.

> **Simple Examples:** alignment / filling

```
#Justify / ALign (left, mid, right)
print("{0:<10}".format("Guido"))    # 'Guido     '
print("{0:>10}".format("Guido"))    # '     Guido'
print("{0:^10}".format("Guido"))    # '  Guido   '
```

We can add next to the `align` specifies which are `^`, `<` and `>` a fill character to replace the space by any other character

```
print("{0:.^10}".format("Guido"))    #..Guido...
```

> **Multiinput examples:** align and fill many inputs

```
print("{0:.<20} {1:.>20} {2:.^20} ".format("Product", "Price", "Sum"))
#'Product............. ...............Price ........Sum.........'
```

> **Advanced Examples**

If you have your custom classes, you can define it's `str` or `repr` representations as follows:

```
class foo(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "...::4::.."

    def __repr__(self):
        return "...::12::.."
```

Now you can use the `!s` (str) or `!r` (repr) to tell python to call those defined methods. If nothing is defined, Python defaults to  `__format__` which can be overwritten as well.
    x = foo()

```
print "{0!r:<10}".format(x)    #'...::12::..'
print "{0!s:<10}".format(x)    #'...::4::..'
```

Source: Python Essential Reference, David M. Beazley, 4th Edition

Answer (score 9):

Use `-50%` instead of `+50%` They will be aligned to left..

Comment: ex: `print "%-30s" % (name)` to print name with left indentation.

Answer (score 7):

A slightly more readable alternative solution:
`sys.stdout.write(code.ljust(5) + name.ljust(20) + industry)`

Note that `ljust(#ofchars)` uses fixed width characters and doesn't dynamically adjust like the other solutions.

(Also note that string addition with `+` is significantly faster in modern Python than it was in the past, but you can swap out `+` with `''.join(...)` if you still prefer that method out of habit)

Answer (score 4):

This one worked in my python script:

```
print "\t%-5s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-20s"  % (thread[0],thread[1],thread[2],thread[3],thread[4],thread[5],thread[6])
```

Comment: Not sure what this adds in terms of differentiation from anything else. and what the heck is thread array?