# best way to left-align strings after padding in python

Tags: python

edit: I think this may be different than [How to left align a fixed width string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684368/how-to-left-align-a-fixed-width-string), because in that question each "column" has data. What I'm asking below is basically whether or not there's a more concise way to have, for lack of a better term, an empty column first. Also, they use sys.stdout.write, and I'm asking specifically about str.format. Maybe that's not the best way to do it, or maybe it is. A comment would be nice to explain why you think my question is a duplicate.

I'm trying to left align text starting after a predefined number of white spaces. Something like this.

```
Title: var01
       var02
       var03
```

I looked at the Format Specification Mini-Language, and this is the best I came up with.

```
>>> print '{0:10} var01'.format('Title:'); print '{0:10} var02'.format(''); print '{0:10} var03'.format('');
Title:     var01
           var02
           var03
```

You can ignore the multiple Python commands; they're just there for demonstration. I just want to see if there's a better way to use `str.format`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684368/how-to-left-align-a-fixed-width-string

Comment: I'm not seeing how this is a duplicate. It's very similar but different in a sense. Can you explain what, exactly, makes it a duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
words = ['var01', 'var02', 'var03']
label = 'Title: '
lines = ['{0}{1}'.format(label, words[0])] + ['{0}{1}'.format(' ' * len(label), w) for w in words[1:]]
print '\n'.join(lines)
```

Comment: I plugged in your suggestion and got a syntax error. It looks like maybe there was a close parenthesis missing, so I added that in and didn't get exactly what I was looking for. When I try 'print lines' it's all just on one line.

Comment: Updated the answer to show how you could print them out.

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly. Thanks so much.