# Unable to Convert scraped data from list to regular string

Tags: python, web-scraping

When I run my crawler it fetches the results as list. However, I expected to have that in regular string being displayed in two columns. Thanks for any suggestion.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url="http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"
def Startpoint(links):
    response = requests.get(links)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    Title= tree.xpath("//p[@class='woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle']/a/text()")
    Link=tree.xpath("//p[@class='woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle']/a/@href")
    print(Title,Link)

Startpoint(url)
```

Having results like this:
[image]

But, I expected the output like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try iterating over both list sequentially, like this:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url="http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"
def Startpoint(links):
    response = requests.get(links)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    Title= tree.xpath("//p[@class='woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle']/a/text()")
    Link=tree.xpath("//p[@class='woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle']/a/@href")
    for i,j in zip(Title, Link):
        print('{:<70}{}'.format(i,j))

Startpoint(url)
```

Comment: Wow!!! This is what I was expecting. Thanks sir Shashank, for such a great solution. Usage of those triple "t" is vague to me, though! Forgive my ignorance. Gonna accept you answer in a while.

Comment: Oh yes, Actually your output was having some spaces so I added that, sorry for that :P because I was trying to do some string manipulation but I failed. but still the output is correct

Answer (score 2):

Your `Title` and `Link` actually don't contain a single element, but both contain **lists** of all the titles and links respectively (those XPath expressions match multiple elements).

So in order to get a list of `title, link` pairs, you need to [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them together:

```
pairs = zip(titles, links)
```

Once you got that, you can iterate over those pairs using a `for` loop, and print the items left justified so you get your columns:

```
print('{:<70}{}'.format(title, link))
```

*(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684368/how-to-left-align-a-fixed-width-string) for details on how to print left aligned items).*

---

Everything together:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = "http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"


def startpoint(links):
    response = requests.get(links)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    titles = tree.xpath("//p[@class='woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle']/a/text()")
    links = tree.xpath("//p[@class='woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle']/a/@href")
    pairs = zip(titles, links)

    for title, link in pairs:
        # Replace '70' with whatever you expect the maximum title length to be
        print('{:<70}{}'.format(title, link))

startpoint(url)
```

Comment: Thanks sir Lukas Graf, your answer solves the problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over each link and print the title and url.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url="http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"
def Startpoint(links):
    response = requests.get(links)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    links = tree.xpath("//p[@class='woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle']/a")
    for link in links:
        print('{title:<70}{url}'.format(title=link.text, url=link.attrib.['href']))

Startpoint(url)
```

Comment: Thanks sir Håken Lid, for you answer. It also solves the problem.