# Shift output of loop toward right side

Tags: python

My code output in python console looks sth like this:

```
1. 0
2. 1
...
10. 15
11. 37
12. 112
13. 4562
```

what to do to make it look like this:

```
1.     0
2.     1
...
10.   15
11.   37
12.  112
13. 4562
```

all numbers shifted toward right?

So here is the code:

```
i = 0
first = 0
sec = 1
fib = 0
numeration = 1
amount = int(input("How many numbers from Fibonacci sequence you want to     see?\n"))

print("Fibonacci sequence:")

for i in range(amount):
    print(str(numeration) + ".", fib)
    fib = first + sec
    sec = first
    first = fib
    i += 1
    numeration += 1
```

Comment: How are you printing? post your code. If you are talking about the console itself (not the print command) say which are you using (regular terminal, ipython, etc...).

Comment: Do you know the contents of the entire sequence before you print the first value? If not, how do you know that the first value should be shifted four additional spaces?

Comment: Please check this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684368/how-to-left-align-a-fixed-width-string

Comment: It is worth noting that it is unnecessary to initialize i =0 and to increment it inside of the for loop. numeration seems to be unnecessary too, here you could just use i + 1

Answer (score 1):

Working from [Python: Format output string, right alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234445/python-format-output-string-right-alignment).

Replace

```
print(str(numeration) + ".", fib)
```

with

```
print("{:<3} {:>8}".format(str(numeration) + ".", fib))
```

This produces:

```
1.          0
2.          1
3.          1
4.          2
5.          3
6.          5
7.          8
8.         13
9.         21
10.        34
11.        55
12.        89
13.       144
14.       233
15.       377
16.       610
17.       987
18.      1597
19.      2584
20.      4181
```

The `3` specifies how wide a column you want for the numeration (including the `.`), and the `8` specifies the width of the right-aligned column for the Fibonacci number itself. `>` and `<` indicate right and left alignment, respectively.