# In line 12,13,14 how can i write code by using f string, without using spaces in f string but in output there must be space between string

Tags: python, debugging, spyder, space, f-string

[code that I am writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTVEX.png)

I tried to remove space but it is not giving me the desired output.[output that I want without using space in f string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJLAV.png)

Comment: Dont use images. Put code as text in question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684368/how-to-left-align-a-fixed-width-string this might be helpful.

Comment: Use wizard for your first question

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you mean when you say that you don't want to use a space in an **f-string**, however, that is exactly how I was able to align the column headers with the results. Note: you may also want to consider using a [pandas dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

#### Code:

```
x=(6/7) * 100
y=(4/7) * 100

print ('1234567890123456789012345')
print(f'Course Grade Percentage')
print(f'ITC    A     {x}')
print(f'maths  B     {y}')
```

#### Output:

```
1234567890123456789012345
Course Grade Percentage
ITC    A     85.71428571428571
maths  B     57.14285714285714
```